# Segmentation Fault within my code

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

This block of code is giving me a seg fault

```
image_t* removeNoiseAverage(image_t* img[]) {

    image_t* average = (image_t*) malloc(sizeof(image_t));

    int image_size = img[0]->header.HEIGHT * img[0]->header.WIDTH;
    int i,k;
    double avg = 0;
    for (i=0;i<image_size;i++){
        avg = 0;
        for (k=0;k<10;k++){
            avg += img[k]->pixels[i].R;
        }
        avg = avg/10;
        average->pixels[i].R = avg;
    }

    return 0;
}

typedef struct image {
  header_t header;      // 15 bytes
  pixel_t* pixels;      // 4 bytes
} image_t;

typedef struct pixel {
  uint8_t R, G, B;
} pixel_t;

typedef struct header {
  char MAGIC_NUMBER[3];
  unsigned int HEIGHT, WIDTH, MAX_COLOR;
} header_t;
```

`image_t` is a struct I made and the segmentation fault happens at the `average->pixels[i].R = avg;`

Did I malloc incorrectly?

Edit: Updated to add declarations

Comment: How do you know how big to make the `pixels` array in `image_t`?  You don't calculate the size of the array until the line after you allocate `average`.

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 1):

```
image_t* average = (image_t*) malloc(sizeof(image_t));
```

This allocates space for `average`, but not for `average->pixels` inside of it. Two pointers means you need two allocations.

```
average->pixels = malloc(image_size * sizeof(pixel_t));
```